# iOS7: Log: MKMapView pitch cannot be enabled on this device

Tags: ios7, mkmapview

Since I updated to iOS7, I get for an app under development always the log message "MKMapView pitch cannot be enabled on this device." The device is a iPhone4.
Can somebody tell me what this message means and how I could get rid of it?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Maybe you've already resolved this. Anyhow I suppose that your warning is because you have selected the check "3D Perspective" in Attribute Inspector of your map view, but your device isn't able to do it. I have not an iPhone 4 so I'm not sure if it can or cannot.
Anyway, if you are not interested in 3D map try to disable that attribute.

[image]

Comment: Solution worked for me too. In Xcode 6.1 the UI label in Xcode is "3D View"